# How can I place a div in another div in php

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I want to place a div id in another div id in a php part.
Here it is the div `id="tekst"` within the div `id="albums"`.

```
<div id="wrap">
   <?php 
      $albums = $albums->get_albums();
   ?>
   <div id="imagebar">
   <?php
      if (empty($albums)) {
     echo '<p>Je hebt nog geen album</p>';
      } else {
  foreach ($albums as $album) {
         ?>
         <div id="albums">
            <div id="tekst">
             <?php
         echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'],'">',$album['name'], '</a>';                               
             ?>
            </div>
      <?php 
         echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album["id"],'"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $album["id"], '/', $album["imagename"],'" title="" /></a>';
      }
   }
```

I got no errors but the text colors should turn red and with no underlines. I tried also to place the test div with the `album['name']` part under the image but I couldn't still not do anything with the test div.

Can anybody tell me how to place here the test div within the albums div?

Thanks

This is the link to the website/live code http://www.robcnossen.nl/

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same id in your page, id attributes should be unique, you should use a class intead

Comment: @koala_dev or just `data-id` :D

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** I guess you're talking about `a` tags which have a default style given by browser (underline, blue color, etc).

If you want your links to have a specific color, or an inherited style, you've to change their style, the following could be a solution :

```
// CSS
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

// OR, as you want
a { 
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
}
```

---

You're not closing your `albums` div

Instead of

```
<?php
    echo'<a href="view_album.php?album_id=', $album['id'],'">',$album['name'],  '</a>';                               
?>
```

You should use this :

```
<a href="view_album.php?album_id=<?php echo $album['id']; ?>"><?php echo $album['name']; ?></a>
```

If you've a decent IDE, it will highlight the code properly and help you to notice HTML errors

Comment: FYI, [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is a language construct. its ok to use `,`

Comment: of course, I'm not talking about the `,` instead of `.` but the fact that echoing the whole HTML makes the code less readable. The syntax stays correct in any case.

Comment: It is not working yet, all the div id's are closed and I have class="tekst" instead of div="tekst". The images are changed from position but that's it.

Comment: Edited my answer, give it a look, I think you're talking about the color of `a` tags.

Comment: Oke, but I also want to position the text part above the image.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMS**

---

You are not closing the tag for `<div id="albums">`.
You have same id for multiple divs for ex: `albums` and `tekst`. You must have unique id in DOM.

**SOLUTION**

---

You can use class instead of id and then in css you can define the design for red color hyperlink text with no underline.

Comment: With h2.tekst a{} I can reach the class but it is all out of position. I tried with position: relative and absolute to get it back in a good position but it is not working. What can I do about this? http://www.robcnossen.nl/